# How to call a function from wp-includes in a php script located in my public_html folder?

Tags: php, wordpress

Receiving a "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_user_id()" when I call this function within my script. My script is located in my public_html folder and not any Wordpress folder. I have attempted to require the pluggable.php file and it did not help. This is not a plugin that is trying to call the function, but a script that is executed from a button within my plugin.

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID=".$user_ID;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_object($result);

$query2 = 'UPDATE booking SET source=destination WHERE status=0 AND 
userid=$data->ID ';
$result = mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: If you aren't attaching this to a hook in your plugin then `get_current_user_id()` cannot be guaranteed to exist. Please elaborate on what your button is attempting to do and why you need this file to be in the `public_html` root and we can probably help you figure out how to do what you need from the plugin itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included only `pluggable.php` file, it is not sufficient for WordPress functions to work. You must have to include `wp-load.php` to all the functions work for WordPress. Make sure to use proper path for `wp-load.php` file if you are using somewhere out side of the WordPress.

Try to change your code like :

```
require_once '../wp-load.php'; //Make sure to use correct path of this file
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID=".$user_ID;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$query2 = 'UPDATE booking SET source=destination WHERE status=0 AND userid=$data->ID ';
$result = mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: I'm using include ('wp-load.php');  and it's working great. Will I run into problems later by not using "require_once"?

Comment: @jameson1128, nope, using `require_once` WordPress will include that file only once, and it will throw fatal error if `wp-load.php` file not found, but i think it will be always there. so no worries.